# How to get Nokogiri inner_HTML object to ignore/remove escape sequences

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

Currently, I am trying to get the inner HTML of an element on a page using nokogiri. However I'm not just getting the text of the element, I'm also getting its escape sequences. Is there a way i can suppress or remove them with nokogiri?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://the.page.url.com"))

page.at_css("td[custom-attribute='foo']").parent.css('td').css('a').inner_html
```

this returns =>  `"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTheActuallyInnerContentThatIWant\r\n\t"`

What is the most effective and direct nokogiri (or ruby) way of doing this?

Comment: What escape sequences? I only see tabs and new lines, which would be the text content of the various text nodes. Please see "[mcve]". Without a minimal sample of the HTML it's difficult to give any sort of detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
page.at_css("td[custom-attribute='foo']")
    .parent
    .css('td')
    .css('a')
    .text               # since you need a text, not inner_html
    .strip              # this will strip a result
```

[`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-strip).

*Sidenote*: `css('td a')` is likely more efficient than `css('td').css('a')`.

Comment: `css('td > a') is likely more efficient...` It'll also return different results if the `<a>` is nested inside other tags.

Comment: @theTinMan Indeed, thanks, greater sign was redundant, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to drill in to the closest node containing the text you want. Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at('body').inner_html # => "\n    <p>foo</p>\n  "
doc.at('body').text # => "\n    foo\n  "
doc.at('p').inner_html # => "foo"
doc.at('p').text # => "foo"
```

`at`, `at_css` and `at_xpath` return a Node/XML::Element. `search`, `css` and `xpath` return a NodeSet. There's a big difference in how `text` or `inner_html` return information when looking at a Node or NodeSet:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at('p') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd635cf36f4 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd635cf3514 "foo">]>
doc.search('p') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd635cf36f4 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd635cf3514 "foo">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd635cf32bc name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd635cf30dc "bar">]>]

doc.at('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.search('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

doc.at('p').text # => "foo"
doc.search('p').text # => "foobar"
```

Notice that using `search` returned a NodeSet and that `text` returned the node's text concatenated together. This is rarely what you want.

Also notice that Nokogiri is smart enough to figure out whether a selector is CSS or XPath 99% of the time, so using the generic `search` and `at` for either type of selector is very convenient.

Comment: This was very helpful! I'm still learning the in's and out's of `at` and `search`, so these examples are greatly appreciated!